# Trying to fork a node module ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

Development for ng2-smart-table has stalled and I am trying to build a fork for the repository but it appears to not build.

I've done similar stuff before and normally just create a fork of a repository. put in my changes and then modify package.json on my main project to point to the github project

However when I try to do this with for the ng2-smart-table I get the error:
Can't install git+https://github.com/atlantageek/ng2-smart-table.git#8f37d374a87a9008328aaea36ad6ce78a28ce7a8: Missing package version

Im also unable to decipher the build release process and the developers have gone dark on the issues.  Does anyone have any guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `version: 1.3.0` to `package.json` in your repository with the current version of your package which npm can track.

And then run

`npm install git+https://github.com/atlantageek/ng2-smart-table`

I've created example commit which solves the issue https://github.com/huncode/ng2-smart-table/commit/8c32e8ccd8ba6274371851d779ffa7d128901964

Then you update the package don't forget to bump version into your package.json.

As alternative you can use git tag (attached image) to fetch exact version from git repository

[image]